# Fixed point of the map $z\mapsto e^{z-r}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that if $r>1$, then the map $z\mapsto e^{z-r}$ has exactly one fixed point in the half plane $\Re(z) <1$.
I have tried setting $x+iy = e^{x-r}e^{iy}$ then compare real and imaginary parts. I also tried integrating logarithmic derivative of the function $g(z) = e^{z-r}-z$ in the half plane $\Re(z) <1$, which does not seem like a good approach.

Comment: Have you tried applying the Banach fixed point theorem? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)

Comment: This might help: You can express the solutions of $z=e^{z-r}$ explicitely with the 
[LambertW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function. If $r$ is real (as your notation $r>1$ suggest) it is $z=-W_{-1}(-e^{-r}))$

Answer (score 0):

You have $f(z)=e^{z-r}$. Now, if $r> 1$, then $\Re(f(z))=e^{x-r}<e^{1-r}<1$. Let $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\Re{(z)}<1 \}$So, $f:S\to S$ Now, if you can show that $f$ is a contraction, then by Banach's fixed point theorem it will follow that it has a unique fixed point.

---

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about Banach's fixed point theorem. In order to apply the Banach's fixed point theorem, we need $S$ (in your notation) to be a complete metric space. However, $S$ is not complete. For example, the sequence $\{1-\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge in $S$.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point, and I also suspect that this function will not be a contraction. So, maybe we have to take another route.